# How to get indexPath match I click send data with segue

Tags: json, swift, uitableview, segue

I hope when I click the `UITableView` row
it will send a ID to next `UIView`
the ID get form json data
I can not get the `UITableView` indexPath
have some error.
How can I fix this ?

this is my code

```
func get(){
    let url = NSURL(string: "http://test.php?id=01")
    let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)
    values = try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSArray
    tableView1.reloadData()
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return values.count;
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SpecialCell
    let maindata = values[indexPath.row]
    cell.name.text = maindata["product"] as? String
    cell.vintage.text = maindata["vintage"] as? String

    ID = maindata["ID"] as? String


    return cell;
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!){
    if segue.identifier == "showWineDetail"{
        if indexPath = self.tableView1.indexPathForSelectedRow{
            let destination = segue.destinationViewController as! ViewController
            destination = self.ID
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: what is the error  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SpecialCell
    let maindata = values[indexPath.row]
    cell.name.text = maindata["product"] as? String
    cell.vintage.text = maindata["vintage"] as? String

    return cell;
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!){
    if segue.identifier == "showWineDetail"{
        if let indexPath = self.tableView1.indexPathForSelectedRow{
            let destination = segue.destinationViewController as! ViewController
            let maindata = values[indexPath.row]
            destination.ID = maindata["ID"] as? String
        }
    }
}
```

Create in destination(ViewController) var ID:String = ""